# LineRender | collision himself with raycast2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i build game with line that you can control his movement.
every few seconeds the line create hole for the player can move through them.
look picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG9rW.png)

now in my code you can see the playerMovement, createLine and drawLine.
i draw the line By player location and every few seconeds i stop draw to millie seconed to create hole and than draw new line.

my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLineNisayon : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] private GameObject linePrefab;
LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public GameObject currentLine;

private bool createHole = false;
private bool drawLine = false;
float rotZ = 0f;

public float speedMovement = 3f;
public float speedRotation = 6f;
public float timingCreateHoles = 2f;
public float widthHoles = 0.2f;

public EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider2D;
public List<Vector2> posLine;

void Start()
{
    CreateLine();
}

void Update()
{
    PlayerMovement(speedMovement);
    DrawLine();
}

private void CreateLine()
{
    currentLine = Instantiate(linePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    lineRenderer = currentLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    edgeCollider2D = currentLine.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
    posLine.Clear();
    posLine.Add(transform.position);
    posLine.Add(transform.position);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, posLine[0]);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, posLine[1]);
    edgeCollider2D.points = posLine.ToArray();

}

private void DrawLine()
{
    if(!drawLine)
    {
        posLine.Add(transform.position);
        lineRenderer.positionCount++;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, transform.position);
        edgeCollider2D.points = posLine.ToArray();

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, 1f);
        Debug.DrawRay(posLine[lineRenderer.positionCount - 1], transform.right);

        if(createHole == false){
            StartCoroutine(DrawHole(timingCreateHoles));
            createHole = true;
        } 
    }  
}

private IEnumerator DrawHole(float timingCreateHoles)
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timingCreateHoles);
    drawLine = true;
    StartCoroutine(DrawLine(widthHoles));
}

private IEnumerator DrawLine(float widthHoles)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(widthHoles);
    CreateLine();
    drawLine = false;
    createHole = false;
}

private void PlayerMovement(float speed)
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, rotZ);
        rotZ = speedRotation;
    }

    if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, rotZ);
        rotZ = -speedRotation;
    }
}
}
```

so what is my problem? i try to create raycast to check collision with the line himself like the game "snake". i tryed to create raycast in function "DrawLine" and i havnt idea how to do that.
my line built by list of vector2 like you can see in my code, its say that i need to compare vector to vector and i dont know how...

*i try collision with the last index in line, not with the circle in the picture.

Comment: If you read the unity docs all raycasts act funny when starting inside a collider.. you can of course mask things, or, make sure you start outside a collider

Comment: i tried many ways and i still didnt successful. i tried use with function edgeCollider2D.Raycast and than  i created array of hits and check if the hit is not the last index, not worked /:

Comment: Well, there is no mask in the code above nor do you start outside any colliders on the object, so, its hard to know what your new endeavors have been, or, why they may fail when theres no supporting code

Comment: i tried to do this: RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(lineRenderer.GetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1),transform.right);
            edgeCollider2D.Raycast(Vector2.right, hits);
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
            {
                RaycastHit2D hit = hits[i];
                if(hit.transform.position != lineRenderer.GetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1)){
                    print("hit");
                }
            }

Comment: That code still starts with inside the Kleider and does not mast for itself so therefore of course that does not meet the criteria I gave you

Comment: C# != UnityScript. UnityScript is a JavaScript derivative created for Unity.